# How to know which columns are updated by an update statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST1" 
(
    "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "COLUMN2" CLOB, 
    "COLUMN3" RAW(16), 
    "COLUMN4" BLOB
)
```

And now I would like to write a trigger which monitors updates, which contain actual changes.

I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TEST1_TRIGGER1" 
AFTER UPDATE ON "TEST1" 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
  dbms_output.put_line ('test1_trigger1');
  if :old.column1 <> :new.column1 then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column1 differs');
  end if;
  if :old.column2 <> :new.column2 then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column2 differs');
  end if;
  if :old.column3 <> :new.column3 then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column3 differs');
  end if;
  if :old.column4 <> :new.column4 then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column4 differs');
  end if;
  NULL;
END;
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error(16,19): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '!='
```

The problem is that Oracle can not compare BLOBS.

How can I avoid the problem? How can I know the columns which are updated by an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`when updating` predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS750):

```
...
begin
  dbms_output.put_line ('test1_trigger1');
  if updating ('column1') then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column1 differs');
  end if;
  if updating ('column2') then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column2 differs');
  end if;
  if updating ('column3') then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column3 differs');
  end if;
  if updating ('column4') then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column4 differs');
  end if;
end;
```

For example:

```
SQL> insert into test1 values ('A', 'B', 'AA', null);
SQL> update test1 set column1 = 'X', column2 = 'Y', column3 = 'FF';

test1_trigger1
column1 differs
column2 differs
column3 differs
```

Answer (score 2):

The `WHEN UPDATING(column)` predicate returns TRUE if the column is included in the update statement, even if the value has not actually changed. If you want to monitor actual changes then you could use the supplied packages:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test1_trigger1
AFTER UPDATE ON test1
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
  if (  (:old.column1 is null and :new.column1 is not null)
     or (:old.column1 is not null and :new.column1 is null)
     or (:old.column1 <> :new.column1) )
  then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column1 differs');
  end if;
  if (  (:old.column2 is null and :new.column2 is not null)
     or (:old.column2 is not null and :new.column2 is null)
     or (dbms_lob.compare(:old.column2, :new.column2) <> 0) )
  then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column2 differs');
  end if;
  if (utl_raw.compare(:old.column3, :new.column3) <> 0) then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column3 differs');
  end if;
  if (  (:old.column4 is null and :new.column4 is not null)
     or (:old.column4 is not null and :new.column4 is null)
     or (dbms_lob.compare(:old.column4, :new.column4) <> 0) ) then
    dbms_output.put_line ('column4 differs');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Good point... I missed the "which contain actual changes" bit in the middle.